# Determine if file is svg

Tags: c#, image, svg

Trying to validate if file is a svg by looking at the first few bytes. I know I can do this for png and other image file types but what about svg?

Maybe I have to convert bytes to string and validate using regex instead?

Comment: SGV file isnt just any old regular image file. Why are you in the situation where you don't know or trust the file type ?

Comment: I need to implement server side logic to ensure that the file a customer uploads is a svg file.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Getting_Started

Comment: Hopefully you're handling the svg files correctly; don't leave any room for executing some scripts if you know what I mean... More specifically what have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: If you allow users to upload SVG, be aware of potential XSS attacks: http://ghostlulz.com/xss-svg/

Answer (score 5):

If performance is a concern and you don't want to read all the SVG file contents, you can use the `XmlReader` class to have a look at the first element:

```
private static bool IsSvgFile(Stream fileStream)
{
    try
    {
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
        {
            return xmlReader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && "svg".Equals(xmlReader.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use an XML parser (you probably don't), then I think a 99%+ reliable method would be to read the first, say, 256 bytes. Then check for the string `"<svg "`, or use regex `/^<svg /gm`.

And/or check for the string `" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\""`.

From my experience working with SVG, this would catch almost all SVG files, with very few false negatives.

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the file using a stream and knowing that the SVG format is a XML, you can simply check it like this:

```
var text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(img);
isSvg = text.StartsWith("<?xml ") || text.StartsWith("<svg ");
```

Comment: This would also allow regular xml files though. Not sure how important it is.

Comment: Yes, your right, in case that case simply can evaluate this part: text.StartsWith("<svg ")

Comment: Note that you're loading the whole file in-memory, and it was asked to look at the first bytes only.

Comment: You're right @AnthonySimmon, thanks for pointing that out. You're solution is much more efficient